# Laravel 4 & Boostrap 3 - weird float display issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, view, laravel-4

I have the following in my migration class for one of the table:

```
$table->float('total_weight');
$table->float('total_volume');
```

When the table is migrated, this is how it looks (in navicat):

[image]

I have the following data in the table:

[image]

When the above data is displayed in my view (using Bootstrap 3):

```
<!-- Total Weight Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    {{ Form::label('total_weight', 'Total Weight (KG)') }}
    {{ Form::text('total_weight', $goods_in->total_weight, ['class' => 'form-control input-lg', 'disabled' => 'disabled']) }}
</div>

<!-- Total Volume Field -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="total_volume">Total Volume (M<sup>3</sup> / CBM)</label>
    {{ Form::text('total_volume', $goods_in->total_volume, ['class' => 'form-control input-lg', 'disabled' => 'disabled']) }}
</div>
```

The total volume is rendering like this:

[image]

Why is the total weight fine, but the volume is displaying like that? Any idea?

Comment: i had this one too, id ended up making the filed decimal to avoid rounding issues like `$table->decimal('total_weight',8,2);$table->decimal('total_volume',8,2);`

Answer (score 0):

The float datatype, in both PHP and MySQL, is an approximate value. There is a lot of literature out there regarding floating point numbers in computer science, so I won't go into all of that. However, you should probably at least look at the [float documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) for PHP and the [float documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/floating-point-types.html) for MySQL.

The basic idea is that it is hard to represent decimals in binary. In your specific case, the reason that it is happening is because .25 can be represented exactly. However, .6 cannot, so it is an approximation.

To see this for yourself, try the following code:

```
// up the PHP precision to see the hidden approximations
ini_set('precision', 20);
var_export(1.25); // exact
var_export(2.6); // approximate
// another fun one
var_export(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3); // false
```

So, if you need to store exact values, you'll need to use a data type that is stored as exact values, not approximations. For MySQL, you'll want to use the [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fixed-point-types.html) type. If you don't actually need to store exact values, but you want to see exact values, you'll need to do some rounding in your views. Also, if you need to do any precise math with your floating point values, check out the [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension.